# Confusion with fillna() when None and NaN values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

When I apply `fillna('New_Value)` to the `df` below it fills all the `None` and `NaN` values except `Column:D` at `Index 1`.

So what is the reason?

Here is my code

```
df=pd.DataFrame([{'A':None,'B':False,'C':1,'D':'a','E':np.NaN,'F':True,'G':'a','H':np.NaN},{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':'None','E':1,'F':True,'G':'b'},
                 {'A':False,'B':None,'C':None,'D':True,'E':2,'F':True,'G':'b','H':None},
                    {'A':'a','B':'b','C':1,'D':'b','E':3,'F':False,'G':'c','H':np.NaN},
                     {'A':None,'B':4,'C':6,'D':'c','E':None,'F':False,'G':'c','H':None},
                     {'A':None,'B':4,'C':6,'D':'c','E':None,'F':True,'G':'d','H':True},
                     {'A':True,'B':False,'C':True,'D':False,'E':True,'F':False,'G':False}])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Question that were caused by a simple typographical error are considered off-topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `None` in that case as `string`. Remove the quotes `'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A':None,'B':False,'C':1,'D':'a','E':np.NaN,'F':True,'G':'a','H':np.NaN},{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':None,'E':1,'F':True,'G':'b'}, ...)
```

If you cannot modify the df, replace the string:

```
df = df.replace({'None':'New_Value'})
```